# Rear right drum brake is heating more than rear left drum brake

Tags: overheating, heat, break, tata

I've bought a new car (Tata Tiago) in India earlier this year, One day I observed some sound from car and checked that rear right brake drum was heated way more than rear left brake drum.

I got it checked with mechanics and it took two 20 KM rides to convince them that the problem was there.

They then cleaned up the shoes, assumed it to be a problem with ABS and replaced it with a new one.

However the brake drum at right is still heating. Though the sound is not there.

According to mechanic it's a normal behaviour but I don't believe so.

Please let me know if it's normal or not and what should be done to get it fixed.

Comment: Heating means the brake pads are constantly being pushed into the drum a little bit.  There should be brake adjustments to fix that, but I'm totally unfamiliar with anything from Tata.

Comment: So, do you have drums or discs at the rear? - you mention pads, brake shoes are used with drums and pads with discs.

Comment: These are drums. They cleaned up the shoes a bit.

Comment: These are ABS controlled breaks and mechanic says that this can’t be adjusted.

Comment: After driving at speed, feel the wheel hubs, they should be about the same temperature.  Are you sure your handbrake is all the way off?  A handbrake may favor one wheel since it is made to be used when the car is stopped, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: How hot are the back wheels getting? Are you sure the warm brake isn't just working normally, while the cool brake isn't stopping enough? ABS usually makes really fast pulses when it turns on, do you feel or hear any fast pulses when stopping? If not, I doubt it's the ABS.

Comment: definitely not normal. There should be no heating at all, in fact when you say "heating more" i wonder is the other side is also "heating"? Any heat that you can feel is too much.  Next this incompetent mechanic will be telling you its normal for rear drums to wear out really fast.

Comment: one bit of advice, try not using the parking brake (if feasible obviously) for a while, see if that lessens the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming all the mechanical parts are good, like the return springs and things (a bad return spring could let a shoe drag & heat up) since the mechanics already looked it over. I wouldn't underestimate the local mechanics, especially if a few at different shops all agree, maybe they know those Tata cars very well and it really is completely normal.

The only other parts are the hydraulic cylinder & hoses, and brake fluid.

- The wheel cylinder could be sticking "on" sometimes (only when hot, etc). Replacing the cylinder (and flushing the brake fluid) with a new or good cylinder would rule it out as the problem.
- If it's a rubber or braided **flexible hose** it's rarely possible that the hose could break down internally just enough to trap pressure in the cylinder, keeping the brakes on.

You could try jacking up the back wheels and pump the brakes, checking if the wheels stop & start spinning (by hand) quickly. Or drive the car until it warms up then check (maybe it only sticks when hot). Checking both wheels would be good too, in case it's really the "cool" wheel just isn't braking enough.

Or, if there's a parking brake cable it could be getting pulled somehow (maybe only when there's weight in the car or something obscure).

Comment: I think you covered everything. I would check the parking brake cable (especially the part where it splits from one to two, the is often some kind of rocker) and springs at the caliper first. it´s easy to check and often there is something rusted and not moving back correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was created by ABS software. Factory technician updated firmware to fix the problem. Apparently, every time brake was applied, it was applied harder on rear right.

Comment: That makes no sense. ABS modulates application during what would be a lock up scenario. Are you saying the ABS module controls braking force in ordinary driving? Well glad you got taken care of!